# Transforming Object Array to Object of Arrays with keys

Tags: java, data-structures, groovy

**My Current Structure:**

```
input:
[
   {A:A1, B:B1, C:C1, D:D1, E:E1, F:F1, G:G1, H:H1},
   {A:A2, B:B2, C:C2, D:D2, E:E2, F:F2, G:G2, H:H2},
   {A:A3, B:B3, C:C3, D:D3, E:E3, F:F3, G:G3, H:H3}
   ...
]
```

**My Goal:**

```
output
[
   {"A":[A1, A2, A3 ...]},
   {"B":[B1, B2, B3 ...]},
   {"C":[C1, C2, C3 ...]},
   {"D":[D1, D2, D3 ...]},
   {"E":[E1, E2, E3 ...]},
   {"F":[F1, F2, F3 ...]},
   {"G":[G1, G2, G3 ...]},
   {"H":[H1, H2, H3 ...]}
]
```

Where "A", "B", "C"... are the literal keys from the original objects, and they are now keys in an object to an array of all values of their type. This is usually simple except for the fact that I **need to maintain the keys throughout**

This is what I've tried so far but I'm not sure if my loop structure is correct.

```
def ArrayList invertReponse(ArrayList input){

    def output = new ArrayList()

    for(i=0;i<input[0].size();i++){ 

        def tempObj = {}
        def j=0
        input[0].each{ key, value ->            
            tempObj[[input][0][i]][j] = value
            j++
        }
        output.push(tempObj)
    }   
    return output
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a job for a `Map`.  Is there a particular reason you have to use an list for this?

Comment: No reason other than the fact that the original structure is a list. I'll look into it

Comment: Seems to be Json data?

Comment: Since both answers are already pretty similar, one can "golf" this a little more by using `.withDefault` on the starting map. `list.inject([:].withDefault{[]}){ m, it -> it.each{ k, v -> m.get(k).add(v)}; m }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the assumptions you can make about the input, you might want to start with something like this:

```
def input = [[A:'A1', B:'B1', C:'C1'],
             [A:'A2', B:'B2', C:'C2'],
             [A:'A3', B:'B3', C:'C3']]

def result = input.inject([:]) { map1, map2 ->
    (map1.keySet() + map2.keySet())
        .inject([:]) {m, k -> m[k] = (map1[k] ?: []) + (map2[k] ?: []); m}
}
```

`result` will end up being `[A:[A1, A2, A3], B:[B1, B2, B3], C:[C1, C2, C3]]`.

I hope that helps.

**EDIT:**

After re-reading the question I see now that what you really want as a result is a List that contains a bunch of Map that each have just 1 key in them.  This may be closer to what you want...

```
def input = [[A:'A1', B:'B1', C:'C1'],
             [A:'A2', B:'B2', C:'C2'],
             [A:'A3', B:'B3', C:'C3']]

def result = []
input.inject([:]) { map1, map2 ->
    (map1.keySet() + map2.keySet())
        .inject([:]) {m, k -> m[k] = (map1[k] ?: []) + (map2[k] ?: []); m}
}.each { k, v ->
    result << [(k):v]
}
```

With that, `result` will be `[[A:[A1, A2, A3]], [B:[B1, B2, B3]], [C:[C1, C2, C3]]]`.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. What if we assume the input is non-rectangular (ie some fields may be null), it is possible to identify those and insert "null" or "0" where missing?

Comment: Yes, you could do whatever kind of mapping you like.  For example, you could represent null with the literal String `"null"`, or the number zero or the String `"0"` or whatever you like.

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to leverage the power of higher order functions as:

```
def list = [
   [A:'A1', B:'B1', C:'C1', D:'D1', E:'E1', F:'F1', G:'G1', H:'H1'],
   [A:'A2', B:'B2', C:'C2', D:'D2', E:'E2', F:'F2', G:'G2', H:'H2'],
   [A:'A3', B:'B3', C:'C3', D:'D3', E:'E3', F:'F3', G:'G3', H:'H3']
]

// Flexibility on merge condition by provding a Closure
Map mergeOn(Map one, Map two, Closure closure) {
  two.inject([:] << one) { acc, key, val ->
    key in acc.keySet() ? acc[key] = closure(acc[key], val) : acc << [(key): val]
    acc
  }
}

assert list.inject { acc, item -> 
  mergeOn(acc, item) { a, b -> 
    a instanceof List ? a << b : [a, b] 
  } 
}.collect { k, v -> [(k) : v] } == [
   [A: ['A1', 'A2', 'A3']],
   [B: ['B1', 'B2', 'B3']],
   [C: ['C1', 'C2', 'C3']],
   [D: ['D1', 'D2', 'D3']],
   [E: ['E1', 'E2', 'E3']],
   [F: ['F1', 'F2', 'F3']],
   [G: ['G1', 'G2', 'G3']],
   [H: ['H1', 'H2', 'H3']]
]
```